# Apply a Gaussian Distribution to all values of a specific column when the mean and std values are dependent of another column values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, gaussian, normal-distribution

Is there any way to create a new column that contains the gaussian/normal distribution of each column value for each another different column value ?

What I mean is, if I have 2 dataframes with the following structure:

```
>> Original Dataframe 1

      Samp     Age     Cs
1       A      51      msi
2       B      62      cin
3       C      55      msi
4       D      70      ebv
5       E      56      gs
....



>> Original DataFrame 2

   Samp   Cs  Age 
0     A  cin   51 
1     A  ebv   51
2     A   gs   51
3     A  msi   51
4     B  cin   62
5     B  ebv   62
6     B   gs   62
7     B  msi   62
8     C  cin   55
9     C  ebv   55
10    C   gs   55
11    C  msi   55
12    D  cin   70
13    D  ebv   70
14    D   gs   70
15    D  msi   70
16    E  cin   56
17    E  ebv   56
18    E   gs   56
19    E  msi   56
...
```

As you can see, **Original Dataframe 2** is a n row repeat of the unique values of **CS** column from **Original Datframe 1**.

To accomplish my goal I need to retrieve the mean and std from the **original dataframe 1** to all unique **Cs** values, so I can further apply it on the **Original Dataframe 2** in the age *Age* column in order to get a new df - **Desired Datframe** with a new column **Probability**.

Since the mean and std for the **Original DataFrame 1** in this case are:

```
m = {'msi': 70.7, 'ebv': 63.2, 'cin': 66.9, 'gs': 59.3}
std = {'msi': 8.7, 'ebv': 11.2, 'cin': 10.2, 'gs': 10.2}
```

Is there any way to as output the following dataframe ?

```
    >> Desired DataFrame

   Samp   Cs  Age  Probability
0     A  cin   51   0.01160
1     A  ebv   51   0.01968
2     A   gs   51   0.02809
3     A  msi   51   0.00353
4     B  cin   62   0.03485
5     B  ebv   62   0.03542
6     B   gs   62   0.03777
7     B  msi   62   0.00455
8     C  cin   55   0.01980
9     C  ebv   55   0.02725
10    C   gs   55   0.03579
11    C  msi   55   0.00900
12    D  cin   70   0.03735
13    D  ebv   70   0.02963
14    D   gs   70   0.02256
15    D  msi   70   0.04570
16    E  cin   56   0.02210
17    E  ebv   56   0.02897
18    E   gs   56   0.03712
19    E  msi   56   0.01100
...
```

This was my attempt to do it so far:

```
def get_age_cs_probs(df):
    df['Probability'] = df.groupby('Cs').Age.apply(lambda x: 
                                                         (1/(np.sqrt(2*3.14*(x.std()**2))))*(np.exp(-(((x-x.mean())**2)/(2*(x.std()**2))))))
    return df
```

Comment: how are you currently generating the probability values?

Comment: with a gaussian formula, see: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IIuXF5QRBTY/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: I know the formula. I meant that you should include the code you are using to generate the values. Are you writing out the formula and saving it as a function? are you using something from scipy.stats? etc.

Comment: I edited with your code sugestion

Comment: I am close to a solution, but I need more of df1 so that it actually has the m and sd values I need to apply to df2

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.stats.zmap` will give you z-scores for your array based on a different array.

this result can be fed to `scipy.stats.norm.cdf()`, which will convert your z-scores into probabilities.

Look into both functions to see if you want to specify different df or other values than default.

I have an answer that generates a list of of probability lists per 'Cs' value, but can't quite figure a clean way to get it back into df2.

```
df1
Out[117]: 
  Samp  Age   Cs
1    A   51  msi
2    B   62  cin
3    C   55  msi
4    D   70  ebv
5    E   56   gs

df2
Out[118]: 
   Samp   Cs  Age  Probability
0     A  cin   51      0.01160
1     A  ebv   51      0.01968
2     A   gs   51      0.02809
3     A  msi   51      0.00353
4     B  cin   62      0.03485
5     B  ebv   62      0.03542
6     B   gs   62      0.03777
7     B  msi   62      0.00455
8     C  cin   55      0.01980
9     C  ebv   55      0.02725
10    C   gs   55      0.03579
11    C  msi   55      0.00900
12    D  cin   70      0.03735
13    D  ebv   70      0.02963
14    D   gs   70      0.02256
15    D  msi   70      0.04570
16    E  cin   56      0.02210
17    E  ebv   56      0.02897
18    E   gs   56      0.03712
19    E  msi   56      0.01100

[st.norm.cdf(st.zmap(df2[df2.loc[:, 'Cs'] == x].Age, df1[df1.loc[:, 'Cs']==x].Age)) for x in df2.Cs.unique()]

Out[119]: 
[array([ 0., nan,  0.,  1.,  0.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0., nan,  0.]),
 array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1., nan]),
 array([0.15865525, 0.9999966 , 0.84134475, 1.        , 0.9331928 ])]
```

This doesn't quite match your expected output, but it would if your df1 had the properties that you list in the question (i.e., the same m and sd values).

Comment: I've managed to get my goals in the meanwhile, but thank you anyways!

Comment: Post a solution if you have one. Other people may have this question in the future